# Is there a way to increase scroll bar contrast in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scrollbar

Well this question is exactly what is says on the tin: Is there a way to increase scroll bar contrast in Windows 10?

Since it seems that it's again modern to hide settings as much as possible, I was wondering if there's maybe a hidden option to change scroll bar contrast somewhere.

Comment: If it was possible in Windows 8, Windows 8.1, or Windows 7 its still possible..  Before I go looking where this setting is, can you confirm, i twas even possible in Windows 7 or Windows 8.x?

Comment: The color of the ScrollBar is shared by other components, so the contrast of the ScrollBar, can indeed be change but it will also change the contrast of other components.

Comment: @Ramhoun To tell you the truth, I don't remember if it was possible in windows 7 or 8. I didn't need the feel to change the colors back then. For me, it's OK to change other colors too, if they're needed for changing scroll bar colors.

Comment: High Contrast mode still exists.  I don't know if that does what you want though.

Comment: `HKCU\Control Panel\Colors` The scrollbar shares the same colour as button shadows saved in registry, see `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors"|findstr /I "shadow scrollbar"`; there is `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors` registry key but the first one is more probable.

Comment: What I see happening in WIndows 10 recently (1809? 1903?), is the scroll bars are **invisible** until you hover over them; I want to throw an Alan Cooper book at my monitor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Cooper ... Whew, just saw https://superuser.com/a/1428068/604333

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of increasing the contrast of scrollbars in Windows 10 is:

```
Settings -> Ease-Of-Access -> Color-&-High-Contrast -> High-Contrast
```

and change the setting from *"None"* to one of the four listed high-contrast themes. That will, unfortunately, make massive changes to all elements of all windows, not just scrollbars. But it *will* make your scrollbars higher-contrast.

Comment: +1 Just for fun!